# Error occurred while running wizard. Telerik.VSX.WizardEngine.ScenarioManagerException: Category: General

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik

when I add a new Telerik form in my project I got an Error.

Error occurred while running wizard.

Telerik.VSX.WizardEngine.ScenarioManagerException: Category: General
Item template: Telerik RadForm
Item name: RadForm1
DTE version: 16.0
Original message: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\16.0_243928ab\extensions\g4vyklmu.pkf\ControlScenarios'. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\16.0_243928ab\extensions\g4vyklmu.pkf\ControlScenarios'.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetDirectories(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption) at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories() at Telerik.VSX.WizardEngine.ScenarioManagement.FileBasedScenarioFolder.PopulateSubFolders() at Telerik.VSX.WizardEngine.ScenarioManagement.FileBasedScenarioFolder.get_SubFolders() at Telerik.VSX.Helpers.ScenarioFolderNavigator.GetImmediateSubFolder(String scenarioFolderName, IScenarioFolder folder) at Telerik.VSX.Helpers.ScenarioFolderNavigator.GetSubFolder(String scenarioRelativePath, IScenarioFolder folder) at Telerik.VSX.Helpers.ScenarioFolderNavigator.GetScenario(String scenarioRelativePath, String scenarioName) at Telerik.WinControls.VSX.TemplateProcessing.WFScenarioManager.Launch(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String itemName, String scenarioPath, String scenarioName) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Telerik.WinControls.VSX.TemplateProcessing.WFScenarioManager.Launch(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String itemName, String scenarioPath, String scenarioName) at Telerik.WinControls.VSPackage.VSItemTemplateWizard.LaunchScenarioManager(ServiceProvider serviceProvider, Dictionary`2 replacementsDictionary)
at Telerik.VSX.VSPackage.ItemTemplateWizardBase.RunStarted(Object automationObject, Dictionary`2 replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, Object[] customParams)
at Telerik.VSX.VSPackage.WizardBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard.RunStarted>b__0()
at Telerik.VSX.VSPackage.WizardBase.CatchExceptionAndSendReport(Action action)

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error is a known issue that is related to shared resources across multiple Telerik extensions. In your case most likely they are Progress Telerik UI for WinForms Extension and Progress Telerik WinForms Converter. To work around the problem you can disable or remove the Telerik WinForms Converter extension from Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Installed.

Best,
Rumen